# copy file content to target file. After last match of pattern in target file. Content from original filed displays on next line of target file

Tags: linux, printing, awk, sed, cat

I have two files,

```
file.1
 $ cat file.1 
this is the stuff that needs to be copied.
and file.2
$ cat file.2
aaaa
aaaa
aaaa
aaaa

bbbb
bbbb
bbbb
bbbb

cccc
cccc
cccc
cccc

dddd
dddd
dddd
dddd
```

I would like to *copy* the contents of file.1 to file.2 after the last match of bbbb.

So it would be something along the lines of:

```
cat file.1 >> file.2
```

but that only appends to the end of the file, so maybe

```
cat file.1 >> file.2 | grep bbbb
```

but that doesn't work like I would like.

The outcome should be:

```
$ cat file.2
aaaa
aaaa
aaaa
aaaa

bbbb
bbbb
bbbb
bbbb
```

this is the stuff that needs to be copied.

```
cccc
cccc
cccc
cccc

dddd
dddd
dddd
dddd
```

Comment: title should display: "copy file content to target file. After last match of pattern in target file. Content from original file displays on next line of target file"

Comment: Show your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: Did you have already solved it. Or you are still waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have some undefined cases.  What should happen in the event you have the following file?

```
aaaa
aaaa
bbbb
bbbb
cccc
cccc
bbbb
bbbb
```

Do you want to read it in only once after the very **last** `bbbb` or do you want to read it in once after each transition from `bbbb` to something non-`bbbb` (in this case, either "cccc" or the EOF)?  If you only want the **last** `bbbb`, then you can create an editing shell-script for `ed`:

```
#!/bin/sh
ed "$1" <<EOF
1
?bbbb?r file.2
w
q
EOF
```

Then make it executable

```
chmod ugo+x my_script.sh
```

Then you can invoke it on the files you want:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec ./my_script.sh {} \;
```

Note that the file-spec (`*.txt`) should **not** catch the `sh`/`ed` script, nor should it catch the template (`file.2`).

If you want to catch the `bbbb`-to-non-`bbbb` transition, even if it happens multiple times in the file, you'd need to clarify that.